# php extract function get variable value

Tags: php

I have a large datatable form. I like to set the database variables dynamically
in this case the form input value submitted is 99

```
$nbs = array();
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        $dec1 = 'q' . $r["sort"] . 'z1';
        $dec2 = '(int) $_POST["q' . $r["sort"] . 'z1"]';
        $nbs[$dec1] = $dec2;
                        }

extract($nbs);
```

This creates the following:

```
 $q1000z1 = (int) $_POST[q1000z1];
 var_dump($q1000z1);
```

outputs: string(27) "(int) $_POST["q100000z1"]"

but if i write the code

```
      $q1000z1 = (int) $_POST[q1000z1];
      var_dump($q1000z1);
```

outputs: 99

I like to get the 99 but something is wrong in my extract method because it doesn't get referenced to the form input value? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the `$_POST[…]` expression in a string. Just do:

```
 $dec2 = (int) $_POST[$dec1];
```

You already assembled the array index `$dec1` there. So just use it for literal array access. Afterwards `$dec2` contains the desired $_POST input value.

(Now what you generally don't want to do is use [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) there. That only makes sense to unfold small in-application arrays. For larger structures, just keep and work with the `$nbs` array instead.)